# Converter string em timestamp para date java

Tags: java

Como converter string em timestamp gerado pelo php com o metodo time()
gerado por exemplo : 1504541885 para Date no java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível fazer isto:

```
Integer timeStamp = Integer.Parse("1504541885");
Date time = new Date((long) timeStamp * 1000);
```

1. [Documentação de `java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Comment: ta gerando Sun Jan 18 06:55:41 BRT 1970. não é isso. time no php gera a timestamp atual

Comment: @PauloRogerio Veja a segunda opção